# Adding <option> to a <select> menu with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm having a problem with this and could use some help. I'm created two `<select>` drop-down lists. The first is a list of reports a user can select and the second is a list of policy numbers.

**HTML**

```
<select name="selectReport" id="selectReport" onchange="ResetDefaultReportOptions()">
  <option value="Make a Selection">Make a Selection</option>
  <option value="All Reports">All Reports</option>
  <option value="Completed Reports">Completed Reports</option>
  <option value="Missing Reports">Missing Reports</option>
  <option value="Closed Reports">Closed Reports</option>
</select>

<select name="selectPolicy" id="selectPolicy">
    <option value="Make a Selection">Make a Selection</option>
    <option value="0123456-001">0123456-001</option>
    <option value="0123456-002">0123456-002</option>
    <option value="0123456-003">0123456-003</option>
    <option value="0123456-004">0123456-004</option>
    <option value="0123456-005">0123456-005</option>
 </select>
```

What I want to do is add an `<option>` to the policy list when a specific report is selected. If I select "All Reports" or "Completed Reports" from the reports list I'd like to insert "All policies" as the second item in the policy list. I'd also like to remove "All policies" if one of the other reports is selected.

**JavaScript**

```
function ResetDefaultReportOptions() {
  var report = document.getElementById('selectReport').value;
  var policy = document.getElementById('selectPolicy');

  if (report != 'Make a Selection' ||
     report != 'All Reports' ||
     report != 'Completed Reports') {
    policy.options[1].text = 'All policies';
    policy.options[1].value = 'All policies';
  }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattSmith/oedodnvu/) of this. Clearly I'm doing something wrong, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function ResetDefaultReportOptions() {
  var report = document.getElementById('selectReport').value;
  var policy = document.getElementById('selectPolicy');

  if (report == 'All Reports' ||
     report == 'Completed Reports') {
     
if(policy.options.item(1).value != 'All policies'){
    o = document.createElement('option');
    o.text = 'All policies';
    o.value = 'All policies';
      policy.options.add(o,1);
}
  }
    else{
        if(policy.options.item(1).value == 'All policies'){
            policy.options.remove(1);
       }
    }
}

document.getElementById('selectReport').onchange = function(){ 
  ResetDefaultReportOptions();
}
```

```css
select {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<select name="selectReport" id="selectReport">
    <option value="Make a Selection">Make a Selection</option>
    <option value="All Reports">All Reports</option>
    <option value="Completed Reports">Completed Reports</option>
    <option value="Missing Reports">Missing Reports</option>
    <option value="Closed Reports">Closed Reports</option>
</select>
<select name="selectPolicy" id="selectPolicy">
    <option value="Make a Selection">Make a Selection</option>
    <option value="0123456-001">0123456-001</option>
    <option value="0123456-002">0123456-002</option>
    <option value="0123456-003">0123456-003</option>
    <option value="0123456-004">0123456-004</option>
    <option value="0123456-005">0123456-005</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you mean "no wrap - in <head>"?

Comment: yes.. correct.. or just wait updating my answer to make it work

Comment: Great! Thanks, that did it. How can I remove "All policies" it I select a different report type?

Comment: @Matt, I think that's a rather different question. And one that, if not answered elsewhere on the site, would be worth asking separately to this one.

Comment: dont understand your use case..why are you adding all policies at first and then you want to remove it or replace it

Comment: @vinayakj, if I select "all reports" or "completed reports" I want to add "all policies to the policy list. If I select a different report I want "all policies" removed if it had already been added previously.

Comment: while adding you are actually overriding the previous option no.1, so is it desirable and so while removing you dont want it restored

Comment: @MattSmith updated the answer to address both use cases